# Applying Stirling's formula to natural logarithm of binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Suppose we have the Hilbert entropy function with $0\leq\lambda\leq\frac{1}{2}$
$$H(\lambda) = \lambda \ln{\frac{1}{\lambda}+(1-\lambda)\ln{\frac{1}{1- \lambda}}}.$$

I would like to show using Stirling's formula applied to the natural logarithm
$$\ln{n!} = n \ln{n} - n + O(\ln{n})$$
that
$$n^{-1}ln {\binom{n}{k}} = H(\lambda ) + o(1)$$
with $k = \lambda n + O(1)$.

I tried the following steps:
$$n^{-1}(\ln{n!} - \ln{k!} - \ln{(n-k)!})=$$
$$n^{-1}(n\ln{n}-n-k\ln{k}-k-(n-k)\ln(n-k)-(n-k)+O(\ln{n}))=$$
$$n^{-1}(n\ln{n}-2n-k\ln{k}-(n-k)\ln{(n-k)}+O(\ln{n}))$$.
After resubstituting $\lambda n$ I get:
$$n^{-1}(n\ln{n}-2n-(\lambda n)\ln{\lambda n}-(n-\lambda n)\ln{(n-\lambda n)}+O(\ln{n}))=$$
$$n^{-1}(n\ln{n}-2n-(\lambda n)\ln{\lambda n}-(1-\lambda)n\ln{(1-\lambda)n}+O(\ln{n}))= \dots$$
And from there I really don't know what to do next. The coefficients are somewhat similar to those of the entropy function but the inside is not a fraction. 
When using the $\ln{(a^b)}=b \ln(a)$ property with $-1$ I get  a nonsense result.
Have I made mistakes in applying Stirling's formula?

Comment: Fix mistakes (why "$\color{red}{-}k$" and "$\color{red}{-}(n-k)$"?) and use $\ln ab=\ln a+\ln b$.

Comment: Thank you very much metamorphy, I fixed it!